Ventana lateral sqldeveloper conexiones
Trabajo con sqlDeveloper en maquina virtual. En algunas ocasiones cuando intento conectarme a mi base de datos me reporta error de conexión y tengo que crear una conexión nueva para poder trabajar. Me sucede también que en la página de bienvenida me aparece mi ultima conexión a base de datos pero por mas que hago click no accede. Cuando creo una nueva conexión en la parte lateral izquierda donde me tendría que aparecer la ventana de las conexiones para poder ver tablas, procedimientos etc. no me aparece.
Desde el menú ver>conexiones no aparece.
Alguien me puede dar alguna pista sobre que se me está escapando
